# Swift async callback is not expanding TextView but it works syncroniously

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, textview, dispatch-async

I am working on an IOS app, where I am setting and auto expanding a TextView dynamically with server data. YES, I am updating the thread on the UI thread using *dispatch_async*.

When using static data and setting the ui elements synchroniously, it all works out fine and the view looks like this:
[image: Sync]

But when I do the exact same thing in an async callback wrapped inside this (delay is a function delaying the execution for 2 seconds):

```
delay(2) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // code for setting ui elements
}
```

the TextView is not expanding the view. I am not using any height contraints and you can see it is working fine synchronously.

The view with UI set in async callback:
[image: Async]

**TL;DR**

Setting TextView with serverdata. It is expanding vertically when TextView is being set synchroniously but it is not working in an async callback. So why does't it work in an async callback, when im accessing the UI thread with *dispatch_async*?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using a delay to wait for the asynchronous request to complete?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout`?

Comment: The delay is just to fake an async callback. Ofc it should be a http callback. Same happens when I use a real http callback.
@Paulw11 I have tried all of these at the end of the callback, nothing worked...:
                        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
                        self.cardView.setNeedsDisplay()
                        self.view.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
                        self.cardView.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
                        self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                        self.cardView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

Comment: Btw it has nothing to do with the tabs view. I get the same error without the tabs. :)